# Reading unicode file in c

Tags: c, file, unicode

I just want to read read unicode text file in normal c.
Following code is not working for same,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *ptr_file;
        char buf[1000];

        ptr_file =fopen("input.txt","r");
        if (!ptr_file)
            return 1;

        while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
            printf("%s",buf);

    fclose(ptr_file);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're reading it fine. The problem is that you're printing it with a non-Unicode function. Also since you're not buffering, you might have issues when a wide character happens to straddle the 999/1000 byte boundary (or 1999/2000, etc.)

Comment: Depends on which form of "unicode" we're talking about. The problem may be what Dave mentions, if it's using UTF-8 (8 bits per token, where most tokens are the same as ASCII representation, but some use multiple tokens to make one character), but it could also be that the text is 16-bit per token, in which case the code is not going to work at all, because it assumes that a token is 8 bits (most likely, could be 9 if it's compiled on some ancient machine)

Comment: Means buffer getting "" every time/

Comment: Well you are going to need to define what you mean by "Unicode file". Do you understand the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    wchar_t buf[1000];

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"it_IT.UTF-8");   // put your locale here

    if ((input = fopen("input.txt","r")) == NULL)
         return 1;

    while (fgetws(buf,1000,input)!=NULL) 
        wprintf(L"%s",buf);

    fclose(input);
}
```