# how to read utf characters in c

Tags: c, unicode, unicode-string

I am trying to read Sanskrit text into my c program. I need to count the occurrence of some letters in the text. i know how to write the logic for this problem .

After going through this
[[Reading unicode file in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372615/reading-unicode-file-in-c]).

I tried to read the same in 'C'. But the Sanskrit letters are not getting 
printed, instead some garbage/ non-readable text was printed.

Can i use a dictionary comprising of Sanskrit letters to achieve my task. I have just installed code blocks on my windows 7, and i am working with it. Do i need something else to get my program working?

What is locale.h and wchar.h .

Comment: For your last question, `locale.h` and `wchar.h` are two header files containing required definition/ declarations. check [man setlocale](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale) and [man fgetws](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetws.3.html) for more info.

Comment: `But the Sanskrit letters are not getting printed, instead some garbage/ non-readable text was printed.`, if you are using "Raster font" on `cmd.exe`, switch to a Unicode TrueType font

Comment: Reading them is one thing, printing them to the console is a completely different thing.

Comment: Do you have Sanskrit unicode font on your PC? If not, you may be able to download fonts from http://sanskrit.indiatyping.com/index.php/download-sanskrit-font.

Comment: What exact code did you use, for what data, and what is the result?

Comment: @AlterMann how to do it in code blocks?

Comment: Where do you input your letters from? Can you view your input in a text editor and verify it looks right? Write your output to the file instead of the screen. Can you view the file with the same editor?

Comment: See also: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: i am reading the documents from sanskritdocuments.org . i am using files which are in utf-8 into a notepad editor and saving it in .txt format. now i want to read these as input to my program, and calculate the frequency of occurrence of some letters in my text.

Comment: If you want to answer a specific user, add their name to the comment like this: @phanitej. If you want to add some general information to the question, don't use comments, use the "edit" link. Let me reiterate. Do not write your results to the screen just yet. Write to a file then view the output file in the same editor you are using to view the input file. Once it's working, start worrying about the screen.