# regular expression doesnt work while execute in c

Tags: c, regex, posix

i am trying to build regular expression with the regex.h  lib.

i checked my expression in https://regex101.com/ with the the input
"00001206 ffffff00 00200800 00001044" and  i checked it in python as well, both gave me the expected result.
when i ran the code below in c (over unix) i got "no match" print.
any one have any suggest?

```
regex_t regex;
int reti;
reti = regcomp(&regex, "([0-9a-fA-F]{8}( |$))+$", 0);
if (reti) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}

reti = regexec(&regex, "00001206 ffffff00 00200800 00001044", 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) 
{
     printf("Match");
 }
  else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
  printf("No match bla bla\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern contains a `$` anchor, capturing groups with `(...)` and the interval quantifier `{m,n}`, so you need to pass `REG_EXTENDED` to the regex compile method:

```
regex_t regex;
int reti;
reti = regcomp(&regex, "([0-9a-fA-F]{8}( |$))+$", REG_EXTENDED); // <-- See here
if (reti) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}

reti = regexec(&regex, "00001206 ffffff00 00200800 00001044", 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) 
{
    printf("Match");
}
else if (reti == REG_NOMATCH) {
    printf("No match bla bla\n");
}
```

See the [online C demo](https://ideone.com/HQHzJy) printing `Match`.

However, I believe you need to match the entire string, and disallow whitespace at the end, so probably

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}( [0-9a-fA-F]{8})*$", REG_EXTENDED);
```

will be more precise as it will not allow any arbitrary text in front and won't allow a trailing space.

Comment: thanks dude,
i have one more Q, i am reading this data from file but when i am trying to read i get no match.how can i check if there is any other invisible characters ?

Comment: @YonatanAmir I am really certain this is not related to the regex. Please [check how to read Unicode files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372615/reading-unicode-file-in-c). It might be related to BOM. Make sure you do not  keep it when passing the contents to the regex engine.

Comment: sorry for the spam it was '\n'